# How do I find the location of the arara default rules folder

Tags: arara

I have been trying out arara. But I can't seem to figure out where to find the  `$ARARA_HOME/rules` folder

Comment: `$ARARA_HOME` is wherever you installed arara. What is your OS?

Comment: I use mac or linux. arara came installed with texlive.

Comment: One way: compile something with arara and then read arara.log

Comment: On my Linux install of TeXLive 2014, its `/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/scripts/arara`. I found it by typing `which arara` and tracing the symlinks

Comment: Thanks. I found that it was properly better to create a folder for my user rules.